# Must declare the scalar variable "@ID_usu"

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Quiero devolver un `boolean` para comprobar si mi registro está vacío, pero me da el error del titulo.

```
    public bool Existe(string ID_usu, int IDPeli)
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT count(*) FROM UserPersonaPelisVistas WHERE Id_usuario = @ID_usu and Id_Pelicula = @IDPeli";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_usuario", ID_usu);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Pelicula", IDPeli);
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (count == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }  
        }
    }
```

Me podrían decir donde o como debo declarar tal variable, gracias :).

Comment: declaras en tu query una variable @ID_us pero le envias "@Id_usuario" los dos nombres deben corresponder.

Comment: Siii, era lo que decía Miguel Zarate, simplemente no sabia usarlo bien y creí que era esa sintaxis, gracias :)

Comment: @AlejandroGarciadeDiego: Recuerda siempre marcar el check verde al lado de la respuesta que te ha solucionado la pregunta, con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud de este sitio. Gracias.

Comment: Si, cierto, se me paso, pido disculpas :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debes declarar tus parámetros con el **mismo nombre** que las has definido en la consulta SELCET.

Si en la consulta defines `@ID_usu` y `@IDPeli`:

```
string sql = @"SELECT count(*) 
               FROM UserPersonaPelisVistas 
               WHERE Id_usuario = @ID_usu and Id_Pelicula = @IDPeli";
```

En la definición de los parámetros debes hacer coincidir los nombres:

```
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_usu", ID_usu);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDPeli", IDPeli);
```

Answer (score 3):

Estimado, tu error es la comparación de parámetros de tu consulta con lo que estás seteando en `AddWithValue`, tu código debe quedar así:

```
   public bool Existe(string ID_usu, int IDPeli)
{
    string sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM UserPersonaPelisVistas WHERE Id_usuario = @ID_usu and Id_Pelicula = @IDPeli";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_usu", ID_usu);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDPeli", IDPeli);
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        if (count == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }  
    }
}
```

No olvides asegurarte además de que los valores `ID_usu` y `IDPeli` de los parámetros que envías sean compatibles con la base de datos.

Saludos!